# JML Error : The .class file appears to be malformed

Tags: java, jml

I am a Teaching Assistant preparing an assignment for my students, in order for them to learn anout JML and design by contract. I give 3 files to them : *RArray.refines-java* (a specification with blank JML assertions), *RArray.java* (the class which implements the previous spec) and *TestRArray.java* (a test class).

In order to perform the work, they will have to compute 3 commands :

1. `jmlc RArray.refines-java` (compilation of the specification and the implementation)
2. `javac TestRArray.java` (compilation of the test class)
3. `jmlrac TestRArray` (verification with jml runtime assertion checker)

In order to do that, however, they have to install JML on the computers at school, where obviously nobody has root access. I tried to install it first, and it appears it does not require any root access - I followed this [French tutorial](https://www.lri.fr/~longuet/Enseignements/14-15/ECP-TVF/InstallJML.pdf), with this [zip file](https://www.lri.fr/~longuet/Enseignements/14-15/ECP-TVF/JML.zip).

I tried on my ubuntu 14.04 laptop, it worked just fine and I have been able to manage some results for the assignment. Even at school, on Fedora, I can install the tools without any complain, and add them to PATH. But, at school, I encounter an error when I run 
`jmlc RArray.refines-java`.

Here is my error :

```
$ jmlc RArray.refines-java
parsing RArray.refines-java
parsing RArray1/RArray.java
typechecking RArray1/RArray.java
The .class file 'java/lang/CharSequence.class' appears to be malformed: Bad constant tag: 18
Fatal error - Unable to find a class for java/lang/CharSequence: error: Cannot find type "java.lang.CharSequence"
```

I tried to search before, and it appears it can be a matter of duplicate CLASSPATHs, or something in those lines, but I could not access it.

I tried also to download the ZIP file again, to verify if this malformed class would be fixed, but no luck.

I tried to run `javac RArray.refines-java`, and it compiles as it is supposed to do, thus it must be a jml issue.

Here is the result of `java -version` :

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Here is the result of `jml -version` :

```
Version: Common JML tools release 5.6_rc4 (Mar. 16, 2009)
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix this? I hope I won't have to discard everything.

Comment: While the question is excellent, it isn't directly for this site. I recommend [Super User](http://superuser.com/) for you. Even if this doesn't get closed you will most likely find more luck over there.